# Uiautomator dump command gives the Edit-text value appending extra text like "editing"

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

i am trying to dump the hierarchy of a screen as a part of project requirement. That screen has two edit-text which has hint-text like "amount" & "desciprtion" with other elements.

It works perfectly fine and generates the dump.xml file with all the information, **But** sometimes in devices like Samsung S5 & Note 2 it creates a problem. What happens is on executing the uiautomator dump command it generates the xml file which contains those two edit-text with text inforamtion like this:

```
....
<node index="0" text="amount. Editing." resource-id="packagename:id/edit_amount" class="android.widget.EditText" package="packagename" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[14,197][706,293]" />
<node index="1" text="description. Double tap to edit." resource-id="packagename:id/edit_tag" class="android.widget.EditText" package="packagenamer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[14,307][706,517]" />
....
```

As one can see here that in text fields it appends values like **Editing** and **Double tap to edit** but actually it's nowhere to be found on the screen.

This issue was coming on S5 with OS version 4.4.2, but after upgrading it to lollipop device it disappeared. but still we have a device like note 2 and may be some other devices as well(which we haven't came across yet) where this is causing the problem.

So if anyone have came across such difficulty and have any kind of workaround, that would help a lot.

EDIT:
Is there any specific setting from developer options that might cause this problem?

Comment: how is it coming when you try to see ui hierarchy with `uiautomatorviewer` ?

Comment: Same as it is seen in dump.xml, with editing.